# Deleting a member of `std::set` by specifying the said member's value

Tags: c++, stl

I have the following c++ code. I am trying to erase a member of a set by explicitly specifying the its value and somehow it seems to not work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

struct compareWeights
{
    template<typename T>
    bool operator()(const T& l, const T& r) const
    {

        return l.second <= r.second;
    }
};


int main(){


        std::set<std::pair<std::string, int>, compareWeights> set = {
        {"A", 4}, {"B", 4}, {"C", 1}, {"A", 0}, {"B", 3}
        };

        for (auto const &p: set) {
            std::cout << p.first << " " << p.second << '\n';
        }

        set.erase({"A", 0});  //Problem area

        std::cout << "\n";

        //Just to print the contents of the new set after erasing
        for (auto const &p: set) {
            std::cout << p.first << " " << p.second << '\n';
        }


    return 0;

}
```

I had commented to highlight where the issue is happening. I can see that `std::set.erase` is returning 0 (not finding the element) but I am not sure why the `erase` method is unable to find the member.

I tried changing the `erase` to

```
set.erase(std::make_pair("A", 0))
```

But still nothing changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your comparator fails to provide a *strict weak ordering*, and therefore, using it in `std::set` causes undefined behaviour. Suppose you change it to:

```
return l.second < r.second;
```

This fixed comparator would be a strict weak ordering, and `{"A", 0}` should be found without issues. However, it would also have another issue: the set would then treat two objects with the same `second` value as equivalent, even if they had different `first` values. You would not be able to insert both `{"A", 4}` and `{"B", 4}`. Also, searching for `{"B", 0}` would find `{"A", 0}` since the set cannot distinguish between the two. To solve these problems as well, you could write:

```
return l.second < r.second || (l.second == r.second && l.first < r.first);
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem, most likely, is with the comparison function. Change `<=` to just `<`.

```
template<typename T>
bool operator()(const T& l, const T& r) const
{
    // return l.second <= r.second;
    return l.second < r.second;
}
```

If you need to order by `second` of the pair first and then oby the `first` of the pair, use:

```
template<typename T>
bool operator()(const T& l, const T& r) const
{
    if ( l.second != r.second )
    {
       return l.second < r.second;
    }
    return l.first < r.first;
}
```

If you want order by the `first` of the pair and then the `second` of the pair, use:

```
template<typename T>
bool operator()(const T& l, const T& r) const
{
    if ( l.first != r.first )
    {
       return l.first < r.first;
    }
    return l.second < r.second;
}
```

Read up on [strict weak ordering](https://www.boost.org/sgi/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html) to understand why that is a problem.

Comment: If I change the <= to <, then the set doesn't have the duplicate values (only one 4 pair remains)

Comment: @Brian showed how to change the ordering more appropriate to my case

Answer (score 2):

The comparator should check if `l < r` and two elements are considere equivalent exactly if  `!(l < r) && !(r < l)`. However, with your comparator, if two elements are equal then both `l < r` and `r < l` evaluate to `true`. In more formal terms: The comparator should implement a strict weak ordering.

To fix that you just need to replace

```
return l.second <= r.second;
```

with

```
return l.second < r.second;
```